# Pass C++ object instance to Python function

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I have a queue of objects that I am dequeueing in order to get an object and process it in python before returning the result. I'm a bit unsure as to how it all fits together but from what I've gathered from various places I think I am pretty close.

I have a class that looks like this:

```
class PyData
{
public:

    PyData(
        const btVector3 &TORSO_LV,
        std::vector<std::tuple<float, float, float>> DsOsAVs,
        std::vector<btVector3> RF_FORCES,
        std::vector<btVector3> LF_FORCES,
        float slope,
        float compliance
        );

    std::tuple<float, float, float> m_TORSO_LV;
    std::vector<std::tuple<float, float, float>> m_DsOsAVS;
    std::vector<std::tuple<float, float, float>> m_RF_FORCES;
    std::vector<std::tuple<float, float, float>> m_LF_FORCES;

    float m_slope;
    float m_compliance;


    ~PyData();
};
```

and then I create a boost python module that looks like this:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(pydata) {
    bp::class_<PyData>("PyData",
        bp::init<
            const btVector3,
            std::vector<std::tuple<float, float, float>>,
            std::vector<btVector3>,
            std::vector<btVector3>,
            float,
            float
        >())
        .def_readonly("Torso_LV", &PyData::m_TORSO_LV)
        .def_readonly("DsOsAVs", &PyData::m_DsOsAVS)
        .def_readonly("RF_FORCES", &PyData::m_RF_FORCES)
        .def_readonly("LF_FORCES", &PyData::m_LF_FORCES);
};
```

After every 33 ms I create a PyData object and place it into the queue. Something like this:

```
// Check the sample clock for sampling
    if (m_sampleClock.getTimeMilliseconds() > 33) {
        if (ContactManager::GetInstance().m_beingUsed) {
            PyData dat = BuildPyData();
            if (dat.m_compliance != 0.0f) {
                std::unique_lock <std::mutex> l(m_mutex);
                m_data.push_front(dat);
                m_NotEmptyCV.notify_one();
                l.unlock();
            }
        }

        m_sampleClock.reset();
    }
```

I then have a separate worker thread that dequeues the queue to obtain an object and send it off to a python function which looks like:

```
void ContactLearningApp::PythonWorkerThread() {

    printf("Start Python thread. \n");

    bp::object f = m_interface.attr("predict_on_data");

    while (true) {
        //printf("Inside while loop and waiting. \n");
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(m_mutex);
        while (m_data.size() <= 0) {
            m_NotEmptyCV.wait(ul);
        }
        PyData dat = m_data.back();
        m_data.pop_back();

        f(boost::python::ptr(&dat));

        ul.unlock();
        //m_ProcessedCV.notify_one();
        //bp::exec("print ('Hello from boost')", m_main_namespace);
    }

}
```

Basically, I am trying to pass in an object instantiated in c++ as a python argument but I am not sure how to piece it together. The python interpreter doesn't need a copy of the object so I am using boost::python::ptr. 
The python file is simple and I just want to print out the object received onto the console like this:

```
def predict_on_data(data):
    print("In Predict on Data")
    print(data)
```

I'm not sure how this integrates with the boost module. What would be the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written some sample code based on your PyData data object; this code uses the boost::python data structures (tuple and list) for exchanging data to/from Python, as this is their intended use, but these can be populated by copying data into them from std::tuple and std::vector as needed.

This works with Python 2.7 and boost 1.53. Hopefully you can use this to help; NB the call to initpydata() (generated function) is required after Py_Initialze().

C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/list.hpp>

class PyData
{
    public:

    PyData() {}

    float m_slope;
    float m_compliance;

    boost::python::tuple    m_TORSO_LV;
    boost::python::list     m_DsOsAVS;
    boost::python::list     m_RF_FORCES;
    boost::python::list     m_LF_FORCES;

    void InitData()
    {
        // simulate setting up data
        m_slope = 1.0;
        m_compliance = 2.0;

        m_TORSO_LV = boost::python::make_tuple(3.0, 4.0, 5.0);

        m_DsOsAVS.append(boost::python::make_tuple(10.0, 11.0, 12.0));
        m_DsOsAVS.append(boost::python::make_tuple(20.0, 21.0, 22.0));

        // etc.
    }

    ~PyData() {}
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(pydata) {
boost::python::class_<PyData>("PyData")
    .def_readwrite("Torso_LV", &PyData::m_TORSO_LV)
    .def_readwrite("DsOsAVs", &PyData::m_DsOsAVS)
    .def_readwrite("RF_FORCES", &PyData::m_RF_FORCES)
    .def_readwrite("LF_FORCES", &PyData::m_LF_FORCES)
    .def_readwrite("slope", &PyData::m_slope)
    .def_readwrite("compliance", &PyData::m_compliance)
    ;
};

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
    Py_Initialize();

    initpydata();

    boost::python::object main=boost::python::import("__main__");
    boost::python::object global(main.attr("__dict__"));
    boost::python::object result = boost::python::exec_file("/home/andy/Python2.py", global, global);
    boost::python::object predict_on_data = global["predict_on_data"];
    if (!predict_on_data.is_none())
    {
        boost::shared_ptr<PyData> o(new PyData);
        o->InitData();
        predict_on_data(boost::python::ptr(o.get()));
        std::cout << "values in c++ object are now: " << o->m_slope << " and " << o->m_compliance << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Python code (Python2.py file in this example):

```
def predict_on_data(o):
    print "In Python:"
    print repr(o)
    # print the data members in o
    print "o.slope is " + repr(o.slope)
    print "o.compliance is " + repr(o.compliance)
    print "o.Torso_LV is " + repr(o.Torso_LV)
    print "o.m_DsOsAVs is " + repr(o.DsOsAVs)
    # modify some data
    o.slope = -1.0
    o.compliance = -2.0
```

Once running this should give output like this:

```
In Python:
<pydata.PyData object at 0x7f41200956e0>
o.slope is 1.0
o.compliance is 2.0
o.Torso_LV is (3.0, 4.0, 5.0)
o.m_DsOsAVs is [(10.0, 11.0, 12.0), (20.0, 21.0, 22.0)]
values in c++ object are now: -1 and -2
```

Hope this is useful.

Comment: I can't seem to find initpydata() function. I know it is automatically generated since the docs says it generates initname() and init_module_name(). I can find init_module_pydata(). Are they the same thing? It looks like init_name just passes init_module_name to handle_exception() in c++.

Comment: In the c++ code in my example the initpydata() function is created (via macro) and brought into scope by the block of code that begins with BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(pydata) {   - do you have this in your code? If so it should be there.